# How to reduce the size of output of nextjs build

Tags: next.js, bundling-and-minification

I cannot deploy the my Nextjs using `serverless-next.js` because the output of the build are so big. I have about 20 pages and each page is am average of 14MB making then too big for a single lambda (using serverless-next.js). One observation I have seen is that the files under `.nextjs/serverless/pages` are not minified. I also see some unnecessary boilerplates in the generated files. Is there a way to reduce the sizes of the files. Thank you.

Comment: Do you run `next build` in order to produce production build?

Comment: I am stuck with the same issue but for some time the following helped me. 
I added the following to serverless.yml

package:
  exclude:
    - .next/static/development/**

Answer (score 0):

In the .next folder, there is a folder called ***cache*** There is a large volume and there is no need for it. You can delete it